# VBA Compile Error: Can't assign to read-only property

Tags: excel, vba

I found the code for VBA to refresh Excel but I get the Compile Error. I am absolutely green to VBA, any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
Public Sub refreshXLS()
Path = "C:\Users\Rolandas\Desktop\OnHoldProcessMtsPrintLam.xlsm"  'the workbook path you want to refresh

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With

Workbooks.Open Path
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
ActiveWorkbook.Close True

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
End With
End Sub
```

this is where i get the error
[image]

Comment: In which line exactly do you get the error?

Comment: `Path` is a property of the workbook i.e `ActiveWorkbook.Path`. Change it to something else for example `Filepath`.

Comment: I tried this code, it's compiled and worked fine

Comment: The code works if you define the variable with `Dim Path`.

Comment: See the answer provided by @TimWilliams in the linked post. If it doesn't help then let me know and I will reopen the post.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I looked at that answer before i posted the question and I have no idea what the answer is.

Comment: @CDP1802 i changed the Path to Filepath but i got another error, run-time 1004, object-difined error

Comment: Ok it is very simple. You have that code in `ThisWorkbook` code area. Right?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes my code is in ThisWorkbook

Comment: ok do this then. Change `Path = "C:\Users\Rolandas\Desktop\OnHoldProcessMtsPrintLam.xlsm"` to `Filepath = "C:\Users\Rolandas\Desktop\OnHoldProcessMtsPrintLam.xlsm"` and also `Workbooks.Open Path` to `Workbooks.Open Filepath`. Also Declare `Dim Filepath As String` after the line `Public Sub refreshXLS()`. Now try

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` and declaring variables would prevent those issues too.